# Spring Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

Currently I'm really at a loss.
I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem anywhere.
I'll start off with showing my code:

**Structure**

[image: structure]

**DispatcherServletInitializer**

```
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 * The type Dispatcher servlet initializer. Replacement for servletXML
 */
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{JpaConfig.class};
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * The type Web config. Replacement for web.xml
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.hitmax.server")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /**
     * Resolver internal resource view resolver.
     *
     * @return the internal resource view resolver
     */
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**JpaConfig**
This is where the problem is. If I change the `JpaConfig.class` inside the DispatcherServletInitializer.java to `RootConfig.class` the error goes away. RootCofig.java is literately an empty class with nothing inside of it.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


/**
 * The type Jpa config.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.hitmax.server.mvc.dao")
@PropertySource("classpath:config/jpa.properties")
public class JpaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Data source data source.
     * <p>
     * In this method you define the properties that are needed to configure a database.
     * In this case it would be PostgresSQL.
     * The properties can be found in the properties document {env}
     *
     * @return the data source
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Local session factory bean local session factory bean.
     *
     * @return the local session factory bean
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("com.hitmax.server.model.location"));
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Hibernate transaction manager hibernate transaction manager.
     *
     * @param sessionFactory the session factory
     * @return the hibernate transaction manager
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Exception translation persistence exception translation post processor.
     *
     * @return the persistence exception translation post processor
     */
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    /**
     * Hibernate properties properties.
     *
     * @return the properties
     */
    final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", env.getProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"));
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", env.getProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

**jpa.properties**

```
hibernate.connection.username=postgres
hibernate.connection.password=password
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hitmaxServer
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
#hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=false
com.hitmax.server.model.location=com.hitmax.server.mvc.model
```

**Role**
inside: mvc > model

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // region: constructors

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // endregion: constructors

    // region: getters & setters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    // endregion: getters & setters

    // region: methods

    // endregion: methods
}
```

**RoleDaoImpl**

```
import com.hitmax.server.mvc.model.Role;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class RoleDaoImpl implements RoleDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public int save(Role role) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(role);
        return role.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Role get(int id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Role.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Role> list() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Role> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Role.class);
        Root<Role> root = criteriaQuery.from(Role.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        Query<Role> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int id, Role role) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Role role2 = session.byId(Role.class).load(id);
        role2.setName(role.getName());
        session.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Role role = session.byId(Role.class).load(id);
        session.delete(role);
    }
}
```

**RoleDao**

```
import com.hitmax.server.mvc.model.Role;

import java.util.List;

public interface RoleDao {

    int save(Role role);

    Role get(int id);

    List<Role> list();

    void update(int id, Role role);

    void delete(int id);

}
```

**RolesController**

```
import com.hitmax.server.mvc.model.Role;
import com.hitmax.server.mvc.service.RoleService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@RestController
public class RoleController {

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @GetMapping("/roles")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Role>> list() {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.list();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(roles);
    }

//    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
//    public List<Role> getAllRolesByName() {
//        return roleService.findAll();
//    }
}
```

If you need to see any more classes please comment so I know.

**I'm making use of Tomcat 8.5.28 and I also tried with Tomcat 9.0.5**

**Logs**
**End warning in server**

```
02-Mar-2018 22:56:44.447 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2018-03-02 10:56:44,488] Artifact server-hitmax:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

**Tomcat Localhost Log**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at
```

**Tomcat Catalina Log**

```
02-Mar-2018 22:56:34.080 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [349] milliseconds.
02-Mar-2018 22:56:44.393 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
02-Mar-2018 22:56:44.447 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

**pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.hitmax.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>server-hitmax</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- War: web application, jar: Java application, ER: Enterprise archive (can contain multiple war files)-->

    <name>server-hitmax</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- region: web dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- endregion: web -->

        <!-- region: Servlet dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- endregion: Servlet -->

        <!-- region: logging dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- endregion: logging dependencies -->

        <!-- region: database dependencies -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- endregion: database dependencies -->

        <!-- region: test dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- endregion: test -->
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Research -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <!-- Research -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- Research -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**My goal is to connect to connect to a PostgresDatabase and implement Hibernate**
Seems like I almost reached my limit to write in this post. Any idea as to how I can fix the Error? I've tried to fix this for over 3 entire days. . . kinda desperate now. (Also it would be nice to know why the error is showing, instead of just fixing it.)

Comment: `EnitityManager` bean doesn't configured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error No qualifying bean of `type'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>'`
means you need to define an entity manager in your JPA configurations - though it is not clear to me why since u are using hibernate session factory !-

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.hitmax.server.model.location" });     
      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      return em;
   }
```

Comment: You are the best!